# How to remove line marks?

Tags: substitution

I have about 900 lines code, and here is what a segment of few lines look like:

```
043 043 1.1 Definicija kategorije\\\

044 044 1.2 Primjeri kategorija\\\

045 045 1.3 Izomorfizmi\\\

046 046 1.4 Konstrukcije na kategorijama\\\

047 047 1.5 Osnove : velike, male i lokalno male kategorije\\\

048 048 1.6 Epimorfizmi i monomorfizmi\\\
```

You see those numbers at the beginning of lines? How to get rid of them, without erasing from each single line, which would last for hours?

Comment: you should be able to remove them all in a second or two in your editor, which would be more robust than removing them in tex.

Comment: yeah, but how to remove 900 times 6 characters in a second or two??

Comment: using sed or perl or any text editor a regular expression replace of `^[0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9] ` to ` ` would remove all such strings of two groups of three digits from the beginning of a line.

Comment: I am using winedt, and I pretty much do not understand what you have typed

Comment: does winedt have "regular expression" replace?

Comment: I do not know even what is regular expression...

Comment: http://www.winedt.org/old/Doc/FAQ/#qa-what.are.regular.expressions

Answer (score 4):

Open the replace dialog in winedt.

Then insert this search template

```
 <[0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Don't forget the space at the end.

Let the replace text empty.

Select the regular expression checkbox and then click on "replace all".

If you selected the "prompt on replace" you will have to confirm the replacement. That is quite good for the first tests.

[image]